# When is it right to use 'to' and 'through'?

Tags: prepositions

What's the right way to say the sentence:

> I counted from one to ten.

or

> I counted from one through ten.

When are the respective prepositions used?

Comment: It's 'to', but I'm curous as to why you thought it might be 'through'?

Comment: books.google.com/ngram shows that in American English, "one to ten" is ten times "more frequent than "one through ten;"  In BrE thirty times.

Comment: I know this question has come up from one to ten times before, but I'm not finding a dupe.

Comment: @Jeremy I have come across such statements: "You can skip pages one through ten". So, I was just curious to know which one is the correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"One through ten" signifies all and each,** usually in sequence.

Example; p436 The Conceptual Mind *Why theories of Concepts Should....Acquisition.* Susan Carey 2015.

> about what "one," "two," "three," "four," "five," ... through "ten"
>   mean.  ...meanings of the words "one" through "ten" from hearing words
>   in cardinal contexts.

Example [Here](http://www.oneworldclassrooms.org/) are the Swahili numbers one through ten

> moja (moe-jah)
>   mbili (mm-bee-lee)
>   tatu (tah-too)
>   *etcetera* to  ... (koo-mee)

& on a Web site for Riddles

> What is the smallest number that is evenly divisible by 1 through 10?

**"One through ten"** would **not** be appropriate in these examples:

> Take one to ten drops in water. // On a scale of one to ten, how
>   focused are you? // Think of a number, one to ten.// "One- to ten-year
>   follow-up results of ..." (certain cures) // One to ten pm: 21:59.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, it's simply a difference in dialects.

I'm pretty sure that in American English, and sometimes Canadian, 'through' is used, whereas in most, if not all, other dialects of English, 'to' is used.

I may not be correct, though, so don't quote me.